# Add CSS to Javascript source in HTML header?

Tags: javascript, html, css, header, styling

I have an html which calls a Javascript. I cannot edit the source script, so would like to edit the CSS styling of some elements in the HTML header.

```
<head>
    <script src="someJavascript.js"></script>
</head>
```

So basically I would need to translate the following Javascript line into html and add it to the script tags somehow.

```
document.querySelector('[title="MyTitle"]').style.display = "none"
```

Could somebody tell me if that is even possible? And if so, how? Thanks!

Edit:
I tried to implement the instructions, but it does not do what I want.
What am I doing wrong?
Maybe I should elaborate more. The html gets embeded as an iframe into another site. It loads a 3D model viewer and in the body the corresponding 3D file. I want to hide one of the buttons in the 3D viewer's interface.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=0"/>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://viewer.marmoset.co/main/marmoset.js">
        <style>
            [title="Layer Views"] {
            display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        marmoset.embed( 'My3DModel.mview', { width: 800, height: 600, autoStart: false, fullFrame: true, pagePreset: false } );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selectors.

```html
<style>
[title="MyTitle"] {
    display: none;
}
</style>
<div title="MyTitle">MyTitle</div>
<div title="SomethingElse">SomethingElse</div>
```

Comment: could you please elaborate how to implement that into the html header code i provided above? For me (I dont do this professionally though) this looks like it would go into a javascript, no? I want to change divs inside of the .js within the html header. Sorry if I just dont understand you answer... Like, what can I add into the html file to change something from the .js it loads?

Comment: @morph3us You only need CSS to change the style.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! I am afraid I just dont get how to properly implement it. Could you please have a look at the code I added to my initial post? It would be greatly appreciated!